# How to include a form in a listing page?

Tags: 7, forms

**I am displaying a content information page. At the end of the content displaying page i need to display a form.**

How shall i do it?

What have I done?

1. Written a menu callback in `hook_menu()`
2. Written a method to collect the information
3. Registered a theme in `hook_theme()`
4. Written hook_preprocess_theme() to register variables
5. Created a template and assign the variables

By doing all the above, I am displaying the Content Information.

What do I need to do, to display a form at the end of the content?

I have done these thing.

1. Created a form in a function called `content_form()` (including logic)
2. Wrote a submission function (`content_form_submit()`).

My only todo left is displaying the form at the content information page.

Comment: <?php print render(drupal_get_form('content_form')); ?>   Just putting this here to get you started ... probably better ways though

Comment: great jukebox.... U r right... I forget to give drupal_get_form... thanks.. Post this is as answer pleze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to print a form defined by [hook_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) is to use the [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) function:

```
print render(drupal_get_form('content_form'));
```